# fail2ban custom action to permanent ban IPs from China

Tags: fail2ban

When a IP address gets banned how can I check if the banned IP address is from China. If yes, then add it to the permanent ban list.

I have found this nice [guide](http://n8wood.wordpress.com/2009/06/22/fail2ban-permanent-ssh-bans/) which write the banned IP to file.

Reason: I am getting a lot of brute force attacks from China daily, thankfully fail2ban is helping restrict this although they appear to be getting worse and they are just changing their IP Address.

Or even better would be if there was a maintained database of known hacker IP addresses.

**Example 1**

```
Hi,

The IP 60.169.78.77 has just been banned by Fail2Ban after
4 attempts against vsftpd.


Here are more information about 60.169.78.77:

% [whois.apnic.net node-7]
% Whois data copyright terms    http://www.apnic.net/db/dbcopyright.html

inetnum:        60.166.0.0 - 60.175.255.255
netname:        CHINANET-AH
descr:          CHINANET anhui province network
descr:          China Telecom
descr:          A12,Xin-Jie-Kou-Wai Street
descr:          Beijing 100088
country:        CN
admin-c:        CH93-AP
tech-c:         JW89-AP
mnt-by:         APNIC-HM
mnt-routes:     MAINT-CHINANET-AH
mnt-lower:      MAINT-CHINANET-AH
status:         ALLOCATED PORTABLE
changed:        hm-changed@apnic.net 20040721
source:         APNIC

person:         Chinanet Hostmaster
nic-hdl:        CH93-AP
e-mail:         anti-spam@ns.chinanet.cn.net
address:        No.31 ,jingrong street,beijing
address:        100032
phone:          +86-10-58501724
fax-no:         +86-10-58501724
country:        CN
changed:        dingsy@cndata.com 20070416
mnt-by:         MAINT-CHINANET
source:         APNIC

person:         Jinneng Wang
address:        17/F, Postal Building No.120 Changjiang
address:        Middle Road, Hefei, Anhui, China
country:        CN
phone:          +86-551-2659073
fax-no:         +86-551-2659287
e-mail:         wang@mail.hf.ah.cninfo.net
nic-hdl:        JW89-AP
mnt-by:         MAINT-NEW
changed:        wang@mail.hf.ah.cninfo.net 19990818
source:         APNIC

Regards,

Fail2Ban
```

**Example 2**

```
Hi,

The IP 60.169.78.81 has just been banned by Fail2Ban after
4 attempts against vsftpd.


Here are more information about 60.169.78.81:

% [whois.apnic.net node-6]
% Whois data copyright terms    http://www.apnic.net/db/dbcopyright.html

inetnum:        60.166.0.0 - 60.175.255.255
netname:        CHINANET-AH
descr:          CHINANET anhui province network
descr:          China Telecom
descr:          A12,Xin-Jie-Kou-Wai Street
descr:          Beijing 100088
country:        CN
admin-c:        CH93-AP
tech-c:         JW89-AP
mnt-by:         APNIC-HM
mnt-routes:     MAINT-CHINANET-AH
mnt-lower:      MAINT-CHINANET-AH
status:         ALLOCATED PORTABLE
changed:        hm-changed@apnic.net 20040721
source:         APNIC

person:         Chinanet Hostmaster
nic-hdl:        CH93-AP
e-mail:         anti-spam@ns.chinanet.cn.net
address:        No.31 ,jingrong street,beijing
address:        100032
phone:          +86-10-58501724
fax-no:         +86-10-58501724
country:        CN
changed:        dingsy@cndata.com 20070416
mnt-by:         MAINT-CHINANET
source:         APNIC

person:         Jinneng Wang
address:        17/F, Postal Building No.120 Changjiang
address:        Middle Road, Hefei, Anhui, China
country:        CN
phone:          +86-551-2659073
fax-no:         +86-551-2659287
e-mail:         wang@mail.hf.ah.cninfo.net
nic-hdl:        JW89-AP
mnt-by:         MAINT-NEW
changed:        wang@mail.hf.ah.cninfo.net 19990818
source:         APNIC

Regards,

Fail2Ban
```

**Example 3**

```
Hi,

The IP 222.133.244.99 has just been banned by Fail2Ban after
4 attempts against vsftpd.


Here are more information about 222.133.244.99:

% [whois.apnic.net node-6]
% Whois data copyright terms    http://www.apnic.net/db/dbcopyright.html

inetnum:        222.133.244.96 - 222.133.244.127
netname:        LCZFFHQ
country:        CN
descr:          liaochenggovermentfanghuoqiang
admin-c:        DS95-AP
tech-c:         DS95-AP
status:         ASSIGNED NON-PORTABLE
changed:        ip@sdinfo.net 20060122
mnt-by:         MAINT-CNCGROUP-SD
source:         APNIC

route:          222.132.0.0/14
descr:          CNC Group CHINA169 Shandong Province Network
country:        CN
origin:         AS4837
mnt-by:         MAINT-CNCGROUP-RR
changed:        abuse@cnc-noc.net 20060118
source:         APNIC

person:         Data Communication Bureau Shandong
nic-hdl:        DS95-AP
e-mail:         ip@sdinfo.net
address:        No.77 Jingsan Road,Jinan,Shandong,P.R.China
phone:          +86-531-6052611
fax-no:         +86-531-6052414
country:        CN
changed:        ip@sdinfo.net 20050330
mnt-by:         MAINT-CNCGROUP-SD
source:         APNIC

Regards,

Fail2Ban
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using Whois for this I would recommend to use an available GeoIP database like http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/

Most programming languages (like PHP, Python, Perl, ...) have bindings to parse those formats easily.

A "hacker IP" database wouldn't really make any sense anymore today, especially due to:

- IPv4 IPs changing owners very rapidly
- Ownership and usage of an IP is ambiguous due to widespread botnets
- Adoption of IPv6 (finally!) makes the first problem worse and keeping a database of 2^128 
  addresses is pretty much a no-go (even though it would probably be sparse)